# Ubuntu 16.04 SSD suddenly full space

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, right now it has 55GB of free space. But recently, this morning, when I turn on my laptop and run `sudo fstrim -v -a` command in zsh to do manual SSD trim, I think there's something wrong with my system. Ubuntu immediately shows an error message and needs to be reported. Then suddenly, I realize that my system become so slow and my SSD space started to be written with a bunch of data (I check my computer properties and my SSD free space reduced from 55GB to only 5GB). Then, I restart my laptop and fortunately, it got normal again and my free space was back. Can anyone explain to me what really happen to my system and what should I do to prevent this annoying error from coming back? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: The first step if it happens again would be to read the error message.

Comment: Why you are trying to play with trimming instead of simple `df -h` (report file system disk space usage)?

Comment: yeah. I always run trim manually, since it more convenience for me. Is it dangerous if I run trim manually? By the way, I always do manual trim for many times without a problem (except for now). @N0rbert.

Comment: thanks for your advice dude. will remember it :) @muclux